# code first classes with fluent APIs

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, ef-fluent-api

I am reverse engineering database for code-first use using "Code first from database" within the Entity data model wizard template. Problem is that it generates classes with Data-Annotations. Is there anyway to generate classes with Fluent APIs with this?

Comment: One option is to use the EF Power Tools. It generates fluent mappings... https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d

Comment: that doesn't let you select any tables etc. Doesn't work for large databases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at options available at reversepoco.com